# How to Convert Byte[] to RSAParameters

Tags: c#, rsa

I have an Byte[1075] with the Information of a RSA Key.
How can I convert it to an RSAParameters?
Byte[1075] are from a database with value varbinary.

DB:
Database Table RSAKey

1. Row: Key | Value(with Key Infomation ind varbinary)

```
byte[] Key = new byte[1075];

DataSet set = con.Select("Select * from RSAKey");
        foreach (DataTable table in set.Tables)
        {
           foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
           {
               Key = (byte[])row[1];
           }
        }

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo; // = Key ??
RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
```

Comment: You can check the binary data on [this website](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) (processed locally via JS) to see if the data you have is an ASN.1 structure. Cryptographic keys are usually stored as ASN.1 structure.

Comment: The fact that it's 1075 bytes is not very informative. You should have some idea of where these bytes came from and what format they are.

Comment: And if it is a public key then please share on this public Q/A site (preferably in hexadecimals).

Comment: How did you obtain these bytes in the first place?